# Can't call JS function, Showing me an error on console log

Tags: javascript

I have this JS code and when I run the code it's showing me an error message on the console log that my calling function is not a function.

**Here is the JS code:**

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.tutor_tooltip = function () {
    this

    // Delegate to tooltip, Hide if tooltip receives mouse or is clicked (tooltip may stick if parent has focus)
        .on('mouseenter click', '.tooltip', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).removeClass('isVisible');
        })
        // Delegate to parent of tooltip, Show tooltip if parent receives mouse or focus
        .on('mouseenter focus', ':has(>.tooltip)', function (e) {
        if (!$(this).prop('disabled')) { // IE 8 fix to prevent tooltip on `disabled` elements
            $(this)
            .find('.tooltip')
            .addClass('isVisible');
        }
        })
        // Delegate to parent of tooltip, Hide tooltip if parent loses mouse or focus
        .on('mouseleave blur keydown', ':has(>.tooltip)', function (e) {
        if (e.type === 'keydown') {
            if(e.which === 27) {
            $(this)
                .find('.tooltip')
                .removeClass('isVisible');
            }
        } else {
            $(this)
            .find('.tooltip')
            .removeClass('isVisible');
        }
        });
    return this;
    };
}(jQuery));

// Bind event listener to container element
$('.tutor-tooltip-inside').tutor_tooltip();
```

can someone tell why it's showing a error message on console log like:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tutor_tooltip is not a function